# Spinner Android Widget size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I'm using a spinner in my activity that only have yes and no element but the size of spinner is large and i'm unable to make it small

```
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_Display"
            android:layout_width="54sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:paddingLeft="3sp"
            android:paddingRight="3sp" />
```